# Is it possible to have a class with an array of class objects from another class inside?

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I have a class called Regions and another class I will call Area. In the main class Area, I need to have an array of Region class objects.

Here is my region class:

```
class Region 
{
public:

    // Constructor
    Region();

    // Get/set functions
    bool getPoly()              {return poly;}
    bool setPoly(bool value)    {poly = value;}
    long getMesh()              {return mesh;}
    void setMesh(long value)    {mesh = value;}
    long getVisibleNum()        {return visibleNum;}
    void setVisibleNum(long value)  {visibleNum = value;}

    // Visibility vector
    void reserveSpace();
    long addVisibleRegion(int region);
    long getSize(){return visibility.size();}

    friend class Area;

private:
    bool poly;          // Does the region have polygons?
    long mesh;          // The reference to a 0x36 mesh
    long visibleNum;    // The number of visible regions
};
```

Now in my area class, I am trying to declare something like this
:

```
class Area
{
public: // Some public class functions
private:
Region* regionArray; // this should be pointers to an array of class objects
}
```

In the Area class constructor, I will allocate the number of class objects I want.

I am getting this error:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed.
Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

So I assume I am not setting it up correctly. It worked perfectly when Region was a struct but now that it is a class, I assume I am doing something wrong.

Comment: How do you include the files, are they in different files, have you added the prototype of one class in the others header, etc.

Comment: The definition of `Area` is missing a semicolon after the closing brace.

Comment: Also, I strongly recommend using `std::vector<Region>` instead of `Region*`. This simplifies ensuring correct copying behavior of `Area` objects immensely. [related FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/)

Comment: _Where_ are you getting "this error"?

Comment: `Region` is not in scope where you attempt to use it. Fortunately you'll only need a forward declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible - do you have the classes defined in the same file?  It sounds like they might be in separate files and you haven't included the header file for `Region` in the `Area` file.

Edit: Also, you have getter functions for the data in `Region`, so there is no need to make `Area` a friend of `Region`.  I would also replace `Region* regionArray` with `std::vector<Region> regionArray`, so the memory is all managed for me.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the problem is that you are referring to a class you have not yet defined. That is the: `Region* regionArray;` line in the `Area` class.

If this is the case you have to remember to include the header containing the `Region` class in the header file containing the `Area` class. Or add `class Region;` above the `Area` class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible. In your case, the problem isn't array. but (most likely) you've not included some header files in some other files.

By the way, you can use `std::vector` as well, which in my opinion would be a better choice, in comparison to raw pointer.

```
#include <vector>
#include "Region.h" //must include these two

class Area
{
  public: // Some public class functions
  private:
  std::vector<Region> regions;  //better than raw pointer
};
```

Read about RAII Idiom : [Resource Acquisition Is Initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)

Answer (score 0):

Other common problem is the `friend class Area;` declaration inside the class without a forward declaration first (I'm almost sure this is the case, are you using GCC?)

In Region.h

```
class Area;  // <- this is a forward declaration

clasee Region {
 ...
 friend class Area;
};
```

Regards